# В мобильной версии не работатет script

Tags: javascript, html

1. Создала форму (класс `.popup`),
2. скрыла её (`display: none;`),
3. навесила обработчик на кнопку (класс `.btn-open`),
4. который меняет класс формы на `.active (display: block;)`.

В мобильной версии данный скрипт не поддерживается.

**Что можно сделать?**

```
const openPopup = document.querySelector(".btn-open");
const closePopup = document.querySelector(".popup-close");
const popUp = document.querySelector(".popup");

openPopup.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
 popUp.classList.add("active");
});

closePopup.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
popUp.classList.remove("active");
});
```

Скрипт подключала в body в конце

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>
```

Comment: а зачем `touchstart`? может лучше использовать `click`?

Comment: click тоже пробовала, не работает

Comment: openPopup.addEventListener("click", () => {
 popUp.classList.add("active"); });

Comment: Тогда ошибка где-то в другом месте. Для кнопок лучше использовать `click` либо события `pointer...`, а события `touch...` надо использовать только для специфичного UX.

Comment: Какой браузер? Что значит "не поддерживается"? Если скрипт должен работать, но не работает, то открывайте в браузере инструменты разработчика и читайте текст ошибки в консоли. Если вы проверяете сайт на телефоне, то подключайте браузер телефона к отладчику на компьютере и тоже читайте текст ошибки

Comment: @andreymal Открывала через гугл на телефоне на IOS, скрипт не сработал, на Android такой проблемы нет, все работает как надо. Попыталась найти информацию о подключении браузера телефона к компьютеру, никак не могу найти источник с понятным алгоритмом действий. Можете, пожалуйста, посоветовать как это сделать?

Comment: Что значит "через гугл" и какая версия iOS?

Comment: Открывала через приложение google последней версии на iphone 11, вроде на нем IOS 13